# How to count the number of occurances of an element in JavaAcript array

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to count the no.of ooccurrence of one particular elemennt in javascript array i,e htdata

some of my code

```
htmldata.forEach(function(htdata){
    htdata['field_name'] == 'heading';
    var char = htdata['field_name'] == 'heading';
    if(char.length > 1)
    {
        alert("hiii");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Given the new information in the comments, here is a complete solution for you. Note that I put the "production" version at the end, after the long form solution with explanation.

```
// The problem:
// Find the number of elements with field_name === "heading" in the
// following object:
const htdata =  {
    0:{id:"199",field_name:"heading"},
    1:{id:"200",field_name:"textbox"},
    2: {id:"201",field_name:"heading"}
}


// The long form solution with explanation:

// convert the original data object into an array so that we can
// use the built in javascript array manipulation functions like:
// reduce, map, and filter.
// 
// see: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array
const haystack = Object.values(htdata)

/*    haystack now looks like this:
    [
        { id: "199", field_name: "heading" },
        { id: "200", field_name: "textbox" },
        { id: "201", field_name: "heading" },
    ]
*/

// now, we can filter haystack into a new array that only includes
// elements with the field_name === "heading":
const filteredHaystack = haystack.filter(i => i.field_name === "heading")

/*  filteredHaystack now looks like this:
    [ 
        { id: '199', field_name: 'heading' },
        { id: '201', field_name: 'heading' }, 
    ]
*/

// now, we simply count the elements in filteredHaystack to get the
// number of elements with field_name === "heading" in the original data:

const headingsCount = filteredHaystack.length

console.log(headingsCount)  // 2


// The more elegant version of the solution:
const count = Object.values(htdata)
    .filter(i => i.field_name === "heading")
    .length

console.log(count) // 2
```

Comment: but the error is  haystack.reduce not a function let me give further clarification

Comment: @raj: map and reduce are es6 features. if they are not functions for you, then you may need a polyfill. what browser and version are you using?

Comment: but the error is  haystack.reduce not a function let me give further clarification   my  array is  htdata['field_name;]: "heading"  i need to count the no.of  filed_names those  values equals to "heading"

Comment: @raj: it just occurred to me that your data is probably an object, not an array. In that case, try: Object.values(haystack).map or reduce.

Comment: Object.keys(haystack).filter(field => field === needle).length

Comment: You can also use the reduce function in my answer with Object.keys

Comment: no it is not an object even though i tried object.values(haystack).map it showing object is not defined

Comment: Object with a capital "O"

Comment: try this: console.log(Object.keys(haystack));

Comment: @raj: I'm on a phone, so it's hard, vut tomorrow, I'll update my answer to use an object like I think you have,but I think you'll probably figure it out soon anyway.

Comment: yes sure when i try console.log(Object.keys(haystack)); it showing their index postions like 1,2,3, the exact strucure my obj is  0:{id:"199",filed_name:"heading"} 1:{id:"200",filed_name:"textbox"} 2: {id:"201",filed_name:"heading"}  so i need to count no.of  filed_names values  those are equal to "heading"

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to count the occurrence of distinct values in an array.

```
var a = ["toto","tata","toto","foo","foo","bar","foo","toto","tata","toto"];
var countPerValue = {};
a.map(function(i) {
  if (!countPerValue[i]) countPerValue[i] = 0; // init counter to 0 for this value
  countPerValue[i]++;
});
console.log(countPerValue); // {toto: 4, tata: 2, foo: 3, bar: 1}
console.log(countPerValue["foo"]); // 3
```

Comment: but it showing uncaught error a.map is not a function